# offer zip for download in php

Tags: php, download, zip

I'm really getting mad after having spent four hours without result. I want to offer a zip file for download. not via link but with readfile (maybe there's another way?) Whatever I have tried, the zip is empty after downloading it.

```
$file = 'Passiv1.zip';
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file) );
readfile($file);
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: check if Passiv1.zip exists

Comment: like @donald123 but also check you dont need a full path to the file i.e. if its not in the same folder as the php code that is running

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file."\"");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Also, make sure you don't have another problem, like Passiv1.zip not being readable.

Try to test that with something like this:

```
if (is_readable($file)){
  echo "OK!";
} else {
  echo "NOT OK!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: no content should be sent before header, not even whitespaces